# Powershell - Replacing first 3 characters of each line in file

Tags: powershell

Here's my little script that I can't get to work.

```
$test = gc -path old.txt;

 for ($i=0; $i -le 14; $i++)
 {  $charCount= $test[$i].length;
    $zero = "0";
    $checkSum  = $charCount + 2;
    $newValue  = $zero + $checkSum.ToString();
  $test[$i] -replace "$test[$i].substring(2)", $newValue ;
  };
sc -path new.txt
```

The idea would be to create a little checksum at the start of each line.

Data should transform from this:

```
XXX80006302
XXX810000175
XXX92063
XXX921802.10
```

to this:

```
01380006302
014810000175
01192063
014921802.10
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you can simplify this using the [string format operator](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-f-operator.html).

```
$lines = Get-Content -Path old.txt
$output = foreach ($line in $lines){
    "{0:d3}{1}" -f ($line.length+2),$line.substring(3)
}
$output | Set-Content new.txt
```

---

If you want to use the `-replace` operator, you can do the following:

```
$lines = Get-Content -Path old.txt
$output = foreach ($line in $lines){
    $checksum = "{0:d3}" -f ($line.length+2)
    $line -replace '^.{3}',$checksum
}
$output | Set-Content new.txt
```

Since `-replace` uses regex matching, `^.{3}` matches the first three characters. `^` is the beginning of the string. `.` is any character. `{3}` matches the previous regex match a total of 3 times. So any character (`.`) three (`{3}`) times. `-replace` only replaces what is matched and then returns the remaining string as is.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately it is not producing a modified output file

Comment: It works for me. What version of powershell are you running?

Comment: Ver 5.1.14393.3471

Comment: Perfect the second method with replace works great. Thanks a million. How would I go about adding to this script that it would take potentially multiple files from a folder and output to a different folder?